# Trying to render multiple API calls on the same page

Tags: node.js, openweathermap

I'm trying to render the results of two different API calls in a node app but am running into a problem.
Here  are my functions:

A disc golf course API call:

```
function dgcrGetReq(res, cityName) {
    var courseData = {
        title: "courses",
        courses: null
    };

    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url:  `${dgcrUrl}?key=${dgcrKey}&mode=findloc&city=${cityName}&state=ON&country=CA&sig=${locationSig}`,
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    axios(config)
    //Await result here to collect data before sending weather request
    .then(function (response){
        courseData.courses = response.data;
        console.log(courseData.courses);
        res.render("courses", courseData);
    }).catch(function (error){
         console.log(error);
    });
}
```

An open weather API call:

```
function getWeatherInfo(city) {
    
    var weatherData = {
        description: "",
        temperature: "",
        wind: ""
    }
    
    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},ON,CA&appid=${weatherKey}`,
        headers: { }
      };
      
      axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        weatherData.description = response.data.weather[0].description;
        weatherData.temperature = (response.data.main.temp - 273.15 );
        console.log(`temperature: ${weatherData.temperature}`)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        console.log(`Weather ${response.data.weather[0].main}`);
        res.render( weatherData);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    
}
```

Here is the render function:

```
app.get("/courses", (req, res) => {
    var city = req.query.cityInput;
    // console.log(city);
    dgcrGetReq(res, city);
    getWeatherInfo(city);
});
```

And here is the .pug component where the content is rendered:

```
extends layout 
block layout-content 
  div.content
    h1.page-title Course Listings
    div#weather-info
      h3 General Weather Information
      p Description: #{weatherData.description}
      p Temperature: 
      p Wind Speed: 
     each c in courses
      div.course-container.flex-container
        div.name-container.flex-container
            a(href=`${c.dgcr_url}` target="_blank") <!-- Link to official DGCR page-->
                h2 #{c.name}
            p #{c.city}
        div.detail-container
            p Holes: #{c.holes}
            p Average Rating: 
                img(src=`${c.rating_img}`)
```

I get the error line "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')".

If I remove the 'weatherData.description' line, then I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app')'.

Any pointers here?  Still getting used to using Node and API's.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- `getWeatherInfo` calls `res.render`, but you don't pass `res` into the function (which you do with `dgcrGetReq`)
- However, you can call `res.render` only once in response, because the first call to render ends the response.

So I recommend changing both `getWeatherInfo` and `dgcrGetReq` functions to return data instead of calling `res.render` on their own. You collect both responses and call `res.render` in the route handler (in the `app.get("/courses", (req, res) =>` function).

Pay attention to the fact that both functions return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), so you need to wait for both  promises to resolve and only then call `res.render`.

Sketch of solution (untested, there may be bugs):

```js
// REMOVED res argument
function dgcrGetReq(cityName) {
    // code removed for brevity

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response){
        courseData.courses = response.data;
        console.log(courseData.courses);
        // HERE return those data
        return courseData;
    }).catch(function (error){
         console.log(error);
    });
}


function getWeatherInfo(city) {
    // code removed for brevity
      
      axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        weatherData.description = response.data.weather[0].description;
        weatherData.temperature = (response.data.main.temp - 273.15 );

        // HERE return data
        return weatherData;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    
}


app.get("/courses", (req, res) => {
    var city = req.query.cityInput;
    var renderData = null;

    dgcrGetReq(city) // returns promise => use then
    .then(courseData => {
      renderData = courseData; // store data in outside scope so they are available later
      return getWeatherInfo(city);
    })
    .then(weatherData => {
      // add weatherData to single object which will be passed for rendering
      renderData.weatherData = weatherData;

      res.render("courses", renderData);
    })
});
```

As additional improvements:

- Add error handling (`.catch`) if `dgcrGetReq` or `getWeatherInfo` returns error
- Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute `dgcrGetReq` and `getWeatherInfo` independent of each other, to generate response more quickly
- Avoid modifying the returned `courseData` (stored as `renderData`) object
- Use [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await)